# Adding points to a boxplot based on another variable

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm fairly new to R and would appreciate some input.  I've created a plot with up to 4 boxplots for each wave (1-5). I would now like to display symbols on the plot for someone responses based on their id. For instance, I want to show the responses where id=202 (id is also in data 'mydata'). I've searched high and low, and cannot figure out how to do it.  Any thoughts? Here's my code (it seems I can't post my image without a 10 reputation):

```
ggplot(aes(y=InnAttMeasure, x=interaction(IntType, wave)), data=mydata)+   
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(IntType)))+
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=23, size=3, fill="black") +
scale_fill_brewer()+ 
xlab("Wave") +
ylab("Innovation Attribute Measure (1-7)" ) +
facet_grid(.~wave, scales="free", space="free") +
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,7.5)) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,7,1)) + 
scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL) +
theme(panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank(),
panel.grid.major.y=element_blank())
```

Comment: It might be worth editing your question to include a link to your image. Even if you can't post an image, somebody could still manually visit the link + a higher-rep user could edit the image in for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but perhaps you can construct an example using one of the built-in datasets. For example, I think this might be what you're after:

```
# First look at the mtcars dataset
mtcars

library(ggplot2)

# Let's make a dataframe of just the Mercedes cars; lots of ways to do this.
mercedes <- mtcars[grep("Merc", row.names(mtcars)), ]

# Now plot a boxplot of mpg by cylinder and then overlay points geom_point()
# of just the Mercedes dataframe
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(data = mercedes, color = "blue", position = "jitter", size = 4)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'll work on linking my image and creating an example with a built-in dataset.  I am wanting something similar to the above, but instead of plotting everyone's response, I only want to plot one or two observations based on the value of a third variable.

Comment: Thanks, JasonAizkalns - the code you provided above was exactly what I needed.   I see how you did it and was able to apply this to my own code. I'm wondering if there is a way to add a label to the dots, like perhaps a 'M', in this case?

Comment: @newRuser to add text, you could do `geom_text(data = mercedes, label = "M")` - however, this is now blurring into a new question. Please remember to vote / accept answers and if you have a **new** question, post it with the required code. Also make sure to leverage search before posting questions. As a new user, there's a good chance that your question (or something *very* similar) has been asked in the past.

Comment: Thanks, JasonAizkalns. I'm just starting to get the hang of this website. I have done many searches and have found most answers to my questions. I did a search for these two questions, but everything I came upon was too complicated and I was unable to get to work. I appreciate your straightforward method.